# Wireshark does not start

Tags: wireshark

I installed Wireshark from the Ubuntu software center (running Ubuntu version 13.10) and got no error messages after.

The problem is that Wireshark splash window closes halfway through the progress bar and then nothing more happens.

I tried to uninstall/remove again and install using terminal and apt-get and again no error messages, but same thing happens.

Any idea what I can try or have done wrong?

Comment: try to run wireshark from terminal and post it's o/p.

Comment: There are something things you can do 1.post output after typing `wireshark` in terminal 2.go to there website and check if there exist any bug that may cause such behavior, you may also get an solution there.

Answer (score 1):

You should start Wireshark with *root privilege* to get your jobs done. You can do this by:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksu wireshark`; you can then do the capturing jobs.

Or, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

```
gksu wireshark &
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to start wireshark by `wireshark` or `sudo wireshark` and nothing happens, you could also try entering `export DISPLAY=:0` before trying again.